# Image not loading after locale change

Tags: android, localization

I'm creating an app (the default language is not EN) with `android:minSdkVersion="8"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`.

I have my `image.png` inside `drawable-mdpi`.

Since I'm now supporting the english language, I've created a `values-en-rUS` folder with a `strings.xml` file with the string translations.

Now if I run my app and change the device language to English (United States) the translated strings are shown and app is working as expected.

Since I want a different image wen the app is shown In english, I've created the folder `drawable-en-rUS-mdpi` with the `image.png` inside. Now wen I run the app in "English mode" it was supposed to load the image in `drawable-en-rUS-mdpi` but it is not.

If i use file explorer and vizualize the app I can see that a folder `drawable-en-US-mdpi` is created and the image is inside.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Ru creating drawable folder dynamically? create folder in your res/drawable-en-mdpi

Comment: @PadmaKumar   Hi. I believe I've created on windows explorer then on Eclipse hit F5 and then clean project

Comment: If English(US) and English(UK) is considered same in your application, then remove rUS qualifier and try again.

Comment: @yrajabi Thanks but that did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

From my read, it seems your problem was the same as mine (image refresh with localized resource on locale change).

My code (simplified) was something like this:

```
ImageView flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagImage);
flag.setImageResource(R.id.flagImage);
```

After reading about and trying out invalidate() and refreshDrawableState() and some other shenanigans, I found another thread [ImageView not refreshing/reflecting changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458565/imageview-not-refreshing-reflecting-changes) where I got the solution to my issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9212097/669399) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458565/imageview-not-refreshing-reflecting-changes#comment18535702_9212097)).

It seems that, if you don't change the resID or URI of the image being drawn, the ImageView itself does not update even if other factors that might come into play have changed (say *locale* for example). The solution for my problem was to add a line that sets a **null** drawable for the ImageView:

```
ImageView flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.flagImage);
flag.setImageDrawable(null);   //This will force the image to properly refresh
flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag);
```