# ImageView doesn't update every x seconds

Tags: java, android, memory, mobile

I have a ImageView which will be updated every "x" seconds, obtained from a server.

The first updating the image changes correctly.

But in the next image has not updated anymore.

Does the first image is stored in memory, I would like to remove?

code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView ==null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.onlinelist,parent,false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holderProfile = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usernameProfile);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv.setText(usersInRange.get(position));
    String[] split = usersInRange.get(position).split(" ");
    final String firstSubString = split[0];
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("xxxxxxxxx.com/uploads/" + firstSubString + ".jpeg", null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(responseBody, 0, responseBody.length);
                    holderProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
                    holderProfile.invalidate();


            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you share you update imageView code......where you are calling this functionality after some time

Comment: he is in a listview, i update the ask.

Comment: for update listview i call notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: can you tell me 'holder.tv.setText(usersInRange.get(position));' is this code working properly or not

Comment: it works, only that the image has not updated the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the Update on a Thread with Background Priority....

You will have to do run it on main Thread

Change this line:

```
holderProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
```

To this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
            holderProfile.setImageBitmap(image);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try invalidate() of imageView after setting image.

Answer (score 0):

Use notifyDataSetChanged(); 
After updating ur image in adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `holderProfile.invalidate();` from `client.get(...)` and put before the

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

or 
you can try this one [ImageView not refreshing/reflecting changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458565/imageview-not-refreshing-reflecting-changes)